# Creating external hive table in databricks

Tags: hive, databricks

I am using databricks community edition.
I am using a hive query to create an external table , the query is running without any error but the table is not getting populated with the specified file that has been specified in the hive query.

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

from official docs ... make sure your s3/storage location path and schema (with respects to the file format [`TEXT, CSV, JSON, JDBC, PARQUET, ORC, HIVE, DELTA, and LIBSVM`]) are correct

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <example-table>    // deletes the metadata
dbutils.fs.rm("<your-s3-path>", true)   // deletes the data

CREATE TABLE <example-table> 
    USING org.apache.spark.sql.parquet 
    OPTIONS (PATH "<your-s3-path>") 
AS SELECT <your-sql-query-here>

// alternative

CREATE TABLE <table-name> (id long, date string) USING PARQUET LOCATION "<storage-location>"
```